# props.children is list of nodes, but the length is wrong?

Tags: reactjs

```
import { PropsWithChildren, ReactNode } from "react";

function Container({ children }: { children: ReactNode[] }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{children.length}</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        {list.map((e) => (
          <span key={'first-list ' + e}>Element</span>
        ))}
        {list.map((e) => (
          <span key={'second-list ' + e}>Element</span>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the example above the container claims to have `children.length === 2` eventhough 6 elements are rendered as children. I'd love to know why that is and what's the best way to get the correct number of children.

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-gauss-p7dvhz?file=/src/App.tsx:0-533)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely here:

```
  <Container>
    {list.map((e) => (
      <span>Element</span>
    ))}
    {list.map((e) => (
      <span>Element</span>
    ))}
  </Container>
```

There are two values being interpolated into the JSX; two arrays of elements. It's like

```
  <Container>
    {arrayOfElements}
    {arrayOfElements}
  </Container>
```

So there are two children. Although React will flatten out the array items into a single container when rendering (resulting in 6 siblings), it won't do it for you before then; the `children` prop will be those two arrays.

To get 6, you'd need flatten it yourself:

```
<div>{children.flat().length}</div>
```

```js
function Container({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{children.flat().length}</div>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const list = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        {list.map((e) => (
          <span key={'first-list ' + e}>Element</span>
        ))}
        {list.map((e) => (
          <span key={'second-list ' + e}>Element</span>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```